# How can I delete all articles stored in my Pocket (aka ReadItLater) account?

Tags: delete, pocket

My Pocket (aka ReadItLater) account has become too cluttered and I want to delete all the articles. Is there an (easy) way to do it?

The Web interface has a bulk edit mode, but it shows only 13 articles at a time and I have hundreds of articles, so selecting 13-at-a-time and deleting is a real painful affair.

Note that I *don't* want to delete my account, just want to clear it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I sent an email to Pocket support and  they provided me with this link

- http://getpocket.com/privacy_clear

which will clear all data.

> This will only remove the content in your account, not the account itself. You will still be able to log in with your account.

This does what I needed!

Comment: Thank you very much @Sathya. This link also helped me so much.

Answer (score 3):

Another option for massive removing unneeded (obsoleted) links in *Pocket for Web* is using [bulk editing mode](https://help.getpocket.com/article/951-bulk-editing-in-pocket-on-your-computer) with a help of **Shift** key.

In the bulk mode with pressing Shift key it's possible to select via mouse click e.g. the 1st link then scroll down to e.g. 3000th link, click again and have all 3000 links selected at once. Then you can either *Archive* or *Delete* them.

With this approach you can safe all *Favorite* links and all tags.